# get object from a shared_ptr of a base class

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Can I achieve regular polymorphism through smart_ptr in c++?

I have these 2 structs:

```
struct Base{... // methods and variables
};

struct D: Base{... // inherited methods and variable plus a few new methods
};
```

And these 2 structs will be used like this:

```
typedef msm::back::state_machine<Base>  ESM; //(Base_namespace::ESM)
typedef msm::back::state_machine<D>  ESM; //(Derived_namespace::ESM)
//The state_machine is from boost lib.
//They (ESM and ESM) are in different namespaces, so no problem using them
```

And in another 2 classes, I have this:

```
Derived_namespace{
class derived_sth: public Base_namespace::sth
{
    public:
    //This method is used to assgin the m_base a share_ptr of type base ESM
    void setPtr(const std::shared_ptr<Derived_namespace::ESM> sm){
        m_base = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Base_namespace::ESM>(sm);
    }
};
}

Base_namespace{
class sth
{
    public:
    void Base_namespace::onStart()
    {
        //!!!!!!!!
        //Here comes the problem, the variable sm turns out 
        //to be null, or some value that causes the following
        //if() statement to be false;
        //So how can I get the correct result?
        //!!!!!!!!
        std::shared_ptr<Base_namespace::ESM> sm = m_base.lock();
        if (sm)
        {
            sm->start();
        }
    }
    protected:
        std::weak_ptr<Base_namespace::ESM>  m_base;
    ...
};
}
```

The method `setPtr()` will be called with type `std::shared_ptr<Derived_namespace::ESM>`, then `onStart()`. So the `m_base` should not be null when `onStart()` gets called.

The specific question is in the comment. Any help is appreciated and I also would like to know the general good practice when it comes to polymorphism with smart pointers. Thanks!!

Comment: please correct syntax errors (such as missing `;` after class definitions). Also, there is no `m_base` declared in `derived_sth::setPtr()`.

Comment: @MooingDuck might be a solution but not really practical for me...

Comment: @Walter Thanks. The `m_base` is a member of `Class sth`, it should be inherited by `Class Derived_sth`, right?

Comment: @Henry: Don't describe code. [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Because the `m_base` in `setPtr` doesn't have an obvious way to access `m_base` since they don't inherit from each other.

Comment: @Henry `derived_sth` is not derived from anything, sorry. Furthermore, you cannot derive if from `sth`, since there is no `sth` (there will be `base_namespace::sth` later).

Comment: I'm sorry, I lost the inheritence `: public sth` when I edited the question.

Comment: There are still many syntax errors in your snippet. This is unacceptable: create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or else don't be suprised if this question will be closed soon.

Answer (score -1):

Polymorphism with smart pointers works the same way that polymorphism with regular pointers does.

For example, let's say I have a class `Animal` with a virtual `speak()` method.

```
class Animal {
   public:
    virtual ~Animal() = default;
    virtual void speak() {
        std::cout << "I am an animal.\n"; 
    }
};
```

I can override this method for dogs, cats, and cows:

```
class Dog : Animal {
   public: 
    void speak() override {
        std::cout << "Woof.\n";
    }
};

class Cat : Animal {
   public:
    void speak() override {
        std::cout << "Meow.\n";
    }
};

class Cow : Animal {
   public:
    void speak() override {
        std::cout << "Moo.\n";
    }
};
```

Now that I have this, I can write a function that makes the animal speak twice:

```
void speakTwice(Animal& animal) {
    animal.speak();
    animal.speak();
}
```

Because `speak` is virtual, this will call the correct version of `speak`:

```
Dog dog;
Cat cat;
Cow cow; 
// Prints:
// > Woof.
// > Woof.
speakTwice(dog); 
// Prints:
// > Meow.
// > Meow.             
speakTwice(cat);
// Prints:
// > Moo.
// > Moo.
speakTwice(cow);
```

This *only works because* `speak` is virtual. And it works the same way with smart pointers, except using `->`

```
void speakTwice(std::shared_ptr<Animal> animal) {
    animal->speak();
    animal->speak();
}
```

#### Using this with `weak_ptr`:

This is very straight-forward too, and the below example will tell you if the pointer was null or expired.

```
void speakTwice(std::weak_ptr<Animal> const& animal) {
    if(animal.expired()) {
        std::cerr << "Animal was expired.\n";
        return;
    }
    auto ptr = animal.lock();
    if(ptr) {
        ptr->speak();
        ptr->speak();
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Animal was null.\n"; 
    }
}
}
```

#### Why your code runs into issues

You didn't provide enough code for us to figure out the issue, although these are some possibilities:

- You didn't assign anything to `m_base`, so it's null when you lock it
- Maybe you forgot to make `start()` virtual? IDK
- We really don't have enough info to solve the problem

Yeah.

Comment: I believe this answer is wrong because `m_base` is a `weak_ptr`, which has nothing to do with anything you mention in your post.

Comment: Two ways: (1) You didn't answer the root of the problem, (2) You appear to have not even know what the root of the problem _was_. Prefer to close questions that don't have enough information to safely answer.

Comment: I was trying to be helpful by providing background information